# How to override a model validation when updating a record in database using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

im trying to update a record from my database using entity framework
the problem is when i try to update the record i get the dbEntity validation error
because i have [EmailAddress] validation on my model , is there anyway to override this validation when i want to update something ?

model :

```
public partial class T
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the update :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateR(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = new T() { Id = id, email = "Deactivated"};
            using (var db = new Database1Entities())
            {
                db.T.Attach(user);
                db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.email).IsModified = true;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.message = e.ToString();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

and the view :

```
  <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.name)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.lastname)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.email)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
      <tr>
          <td>@Html.DisplayFor(mitem => item.name)</td>
          <td>@Html.DisplayFor(mitem => item.lastname)</td>
          <td>@Html.DisplayFor(mitem => item.email)</td>
          <td>@Html.ActionLink("Update", "UpdateR", new { id = item.Id})
</td>
      </tr>
  }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit :**

```
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Just before db.SaveChanges(); worked for me if anyone had the same question.

[Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.validateonsaveenabled(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: `email = "Deactivated"` makes no sense (its not an email address). What are you trying to indicate by setting that?

Comment: You are updating the email to invalid email address, you cannot override that

Comment: its actually email = email + " | Deactivated" , and its for admin to see the deactivated users in users pannel

Comment: Just add a `bool` property to your model/table to indicate if its been deactivated

Comment: @StephenMuecke i thought of that as alternate , i just wanted to see if this is possible , so there's no way

Comment: Not unless you create a valid email address. But if your want admin to see 'deactivated' users, then having a `bool` property makes sense and its easy to query

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok , Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the [DbContextConfiguration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.validateonsaveenabled(v=vs.113).aspx) to false.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateR(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        var user = new T() { Id = id, email = "Deactivated"};
        using (var db = new Database1Entities())
        {
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            db.T.Attach(user);
            db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.email).IsModified = true;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ViewBag.message = e.ToString();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain why the solution works.  Simply pasting code is not useful if the OP (and future readers) have to search through your code to figure it out (and sometimes they may not understand by just looking at code).

Comment: @ErikPhilips i added the refrence on top , is that enough ?

Comment: I added a tad more